# How can I prevent sweetAlert2 from closing upon clicking closing button?

Tags: javascript, html, sweetalert2

I have a project in which I allow users to save text templates inside a modal. If the user has not saved the current template and wants to close the modal, I want to stop the closing and not proceed with it unless the user wants to follow without saving. So far I have this:

```
const closeButton = document.querySelector(".swal2-close");
closeButton.addEventListener("click", async (event) => {
    const saveButton = document.querySelector("#saveTemplateButton");
    if (!saveButton.disabled) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        const continueSave = await this.continueWithoutSavingChanges();
        if (continueSave) {
            Swal.close();
        }
    }
});
```

In the code `this.continueWithoutSavingChanges()` opens a toast that expects a YES/NO answer from the user, and if yes, then it should close. So far, the modal is closed as soon as the closing button is clicked, and there is no waiting time for the toast.

Is there a way to make this work?